# Store data in mongodb with java

Tags: java, xml, mongodb

I'm trying to insert data ( contents of xml file) in mongodb :

```
 ArrayList<Object> map = new ArrayList<Object>();
          try
          {

              File file = new File ("test.xml");
              InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
              StringBuilder builder =  new StringBuilder();
              int ptr = 0;
              while ((ptr = inputStream.read()) != -1 )

                  {
                      builder.append((char) ptr);

                  }

               String xml  = builder.toString();
               inputStream.close();   
               org.json.JSONArray jsonarray = JSONML.toJSONArray(xml);

               // jsonArray to map
               map=  toList(jsonarray); 
                DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("test");

                 //get a single collection 
                 DBCollection dbcollection = db.getCollection("mycoll");



            //insert the list of object in mongodb ? ? ?
```

but I don't know how to insert from the list of object ( json) in mongodb ?
Is there any other way to extract data from xml and store it in mongo (keeping the structure of the XML file, wihtout parsing the file)

Answer (score -1):

```
        //After Getting collection , you can insert the document. Here is the code snippet.




 BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("a", "b");
        document.put("c", "d");

        BasicDBObject documentDetail = new BasicDBObject();
        documentDetail.put("e", new ArrayList<String>());

        document.put("xyz", documentDetail);

        collection.insert(document);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, the problem is that i don't have ("a" , "b")... i just have a list of object :  org.json.JSONArray jsonarray = JSONML.toJSONArray(xml);
  // jsonArray to map :
               map=  toList(jsonarray);  i don't have the values

Comment: Thank you, can you please put me the link to check it out